# Displaying IEEE 754 floating point representation in GDB?

Tags: floating-point, gdb

When I ask GDB to print a real in binary, I get this:

```
(gdb) p/t 5210887.5
$1 = 10011111000001100000111
```

According to [this](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html),

```
0 10010101 00111110000011000001111
```

is the expected value.

Aligning them,

```
         1 0011111000001100000111
0 10010101 00111110000011000001111
```

And it looks like GDB is giving me the integer representation after rounding. Thing is it was doing this with a variable at work as well. Using a declaration in a C program -

```
main()
{
  float f = 5210887.5;
}
```

and debugging it -

```
$ gcc -g -O0 floatdec.c -o floatdec
$ gdb floatdec
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-60.el6_4.1)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/ /floatdec...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804839a: file floatdec.c, line 3.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/ /floatdec 

Breakpoint 1, main () at floatdec.c:3
3         float f = 5210887.5;
(gdb) s
4       }
(gdb) p f
$1 = 5210887.5
(gdb) p/t f
$2 = 10011111000001100000111
```

same thing, it is showing me the integer representation. Is there no way to have GDB show me the floating point format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `t` format does indeed convert the value to an integer. From [gdb: Output Formats](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Formats.html):

> ```
> t
>    Print as integer in binary. The letter ‘t’ stands for “two”.
> ```

This is backed up by the code in gdb's `print_scalar_formatted`:

```
if (options->format != 'f')
    val_long = unpack_long (type, valaddr);
```

where `unpack_long` converts various types of values, including float, into a long.

A workaround is to take the address of the variable, cast it to an (int32 *), and dereference that.

```
(gdb) p f
$2 = 5210887.5
(gdb) p/t *(int32_t *)&f
$3 = 1001010100111110000011000001111
(gdb) p/t {int32_t}&f
$4 = 1001010100111110000011000001111
```

Or, at the language-independent level, using the `x` command:

```
(gdb) x/tw &f
0xbffff3f4: 01001010100111110000011000001111
```

This was done on an x86. Other-endian systems may produce a different bit pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without a file loaded, you can cast to a `void *` and print that

```
(gdb) p/t (void *) 5210887.5f
$1 = 1001010100111110000011000001111
```

You can also convert back by then casting it to a float

```
(gdb) p (float) (void*) 0b1001010100111110000011000001111
$2 = 5210887.5
```